# General rule for translating a combined word like "fish farm" "car factory" “dog story”

Tags: translation

A *fish farm* is a farm that farms fish. A *car factory* is a factory that makes cars. A *dog story* is a story about dogs. Point it, it looks like you can just put noun next to noun in English, and voila!

In Esperanto, sometimes there are suffixes (e.g. -*ejo*), but otherwise, there seem to be several ways to translate such words:

- A de B (*fabriko de auxtoj*) (sometimes *de la*, instead of just *de*)
- A-a B-o (*auta fabriko*)
- A-B (*autfabriko*/*autofabriko*)

I would like to know, what is the best practice (in general) to translate such noun-noun words in English?

Comment: And a _cough medicine_ is a medicine that makes you cough... :) Don't forget that the meaning of compound nouns in English is not that straight forward, as there can be a range of semantic relationships between the two nouns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"How do I translate" is the wrong question. The question should be "I have an idea - how do I express it?" or "how does compounding work in Esperanto."

The PMEG article on [Vortfarado](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/principoj/antauelementoj.html) will be helpful as an introduction.

A garden for growing flowers is a *florĝardeno*. A factory for making cars is a *aŭtofabriko*. A story about dogs is a *rakonto pri hundoj.*

Comment: PMEG Vortfarado says it all.

Comment: Yes, I thought about making that my entire reply but there seems to be a rule against link-only replies. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I think you are asking what is the general rule of compounding two nouns in Esperanto. If I am right, Plena Manlibro de Esperanta Gramatiko (or PMEG) gives the best odds of satisfying your curiosity.

As far as I recall, there are two ways to compound two Esperanto nouns:
**poŝo** + mono = **poŝo**mono / **poŝ**mono

Comment: Would it be possible to check your recollection and edit the line about "as far as I recall"? If you're not sure, don't answer. If you're sure, say you're sure.

Answer (score 2):

There is no best-practice, general way to translate such noun-noun pairs in English into Esperanto.

But my general *advice* would be to always try to be more specific in Esperanto than the English is. Because the Esperanto translation will lack the English-usage context that can make the English phrase work in English.